# why does i cannot run the npm commands

Tags: node.js, npm

here is the error when i run npm run start or nump start or any other npm command

````
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall open
 npm ERR! path C:\Users\Rana\Desktop\news app/package.json
 npm ERR! errno -4058
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Rana\Desktop\news 
 app\package.json'
 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
 npm ERR! enoent
 
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-05T14_41_56_734Z-debug- 
 0.log```
````

Comment: npm commands (start, run, etc.,) work only if their corresponding commands of the framework you work with are available inside the scripts object of package.json. Which appears to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm init` to create a project and then assign your npm commands inside the package.json that has been created. [Use this reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init).